# select query with multiple values

Tags: php, sql

I  have tbl which consists of date and show timings in that i want to select distinct date from tbl

```
date             |  from  | time  
2013-09-10         9:30     12:30
2013-09-10         12:30    1:00
```

and the o/p should be

```
date            |  show timngs 
2013-09-10         9:30-12-30  | 12:30 -1:00
```

i tried the sql statement like

```
"SELECT * FROM `shows` WHERE `movid` = '$id' ORDER BY date
```

and o/p i got is

```
2013-09-10  09:00 AM-11:00 AM
2013-09-10  09:00 AM-11:00 AM
```

how to get in above format help me out

Thanks in adance..

ameeth

Answer (score 0):

try to group by date :

```
SELECT 
  date, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(from,'-',time) SEPARATOR ' | ') 
FROM 
  table 
GROUP BY 
  date;
```

Comment: i'll send what i tried http://pastebin.com/rR7NfpQP  i should get o/p in a table format